# Login in a third website

Tags: javascript

I work for a company called Culinary Crafts. I am trying to create a simple app just to learn a little bit more about HTML. They have a website where you login in and claim or unclaim your shifts. I am trying to make an app for that but using the website that already exists (since I do not have access to anything there, only to my personal account). The website is this one: http://staffing.culinarycrafts.com/

This is how my app is looking:
[App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vcf5.png)

This is my HTML for the login and password:

```
<label><b>Username</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

<label><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
```

Is there any way to use the login and password that the user inputs to login on the original website? And after doing the login, is the any way to navigate on the website?

Comment: That depends on the third-party website itself. However it is strongly advices not to do so due to security reasons, unless the third-party is willing to cooperate with yours

Comment: No, absolutely not. The good way is to use their API, if available. There are other ways to do what you want, but that's strongly not recommended.

Comment: So is it illegal? =/ crap

Comment: I wont do it than..

Comment: Not illegal, but opens you up to a great many security issues unless they have an API.

Comment: It's a bad idea because it encourages the users of this app to compromise their security.  Now, you're probably not a jerk, but imagine if you were, and you wrote an app that took people's usernames and passwords and logged them in on the company site - and also saved off a copy of their usernames/passwords for your own use.

Comment: Of course you can. I'd advise you to get permission first though. One way you could do it is, set the `action` attribute inside your form to `http://staffing.culinarycrafts.com/ulogin.php`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should get permission for doing it,

now lets come to the part of doing it.

1. use temper data plugin to see what data it sends to server for login and what it gets in return.
2. chances are it won't allow you to make call though ajax for login so go for curl, that will require the server side scripting.
3. store the cookies in curl and do whatever you wish.